# Need help with limit of sequence: $\lim_{x \to +\infty}= \frac{n!-n^3}{n^5-e^n+3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}= \frac{n!-n^3}{n^5-e^n+3}$$
I tried to use it by dividing by both $n^3$ and $n!$ and using note forms of limits of sequence but all I'm getting is indeterminations... The result should be $-\infty$. 
Anyone can give me some clues on how to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean "The result should be minus infinity"?

Comment: @imranfat I mean the sequence should diverge to -infinity, as n approaches infinity.

Comment: Why should it ?

Comment: @imranfat Mmm because that's what sequences do? I'm not sure I'm getting your point :)

Comment: My point is, is the answer key saying that the answer is minus infinity, or do you have an inclination that it is minus infinity? Of course, not all sequences go to minus infinity, right? One way of looking at it, what is the dominant term in the numerator and what is the dominant term in the denominator...

Comment: @imranfat Yes, the answer key says that, and so does wolframalpha so I'm assuming it's correct. Not all sequences go to minus infinity, this one does so I'm trying to understand how come.

Comment: Ok, what are the dominant terms in your numerator and denominator?

Comment: Should be $n!$ and $e^n$

Comment: Yes, but that e-power has a negative up front...I think this should do it...

Comment: @imranfat I was so blind about that... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that $n!>(n/2)^{n/2}$.  Thus, we see that

$$\frac{n!}{e^n}\ge \left(\frac{n}{2e^2}\right)^{n/2}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}$ by Stirling's approximation

Comment: That's a big gun to use here.

Comment: @zhw. but it's my favorite :(

Comment: I don't think I'm supposed to use that, as I never heard of it :(

Comment: @user3501165 ok! It is a very useful approximation to know though

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For $n>2,$

$$\frac{e^n}{n!} =\frac{e}{n}\frac{e}{n-1} \cdots \frac{e}{3} \cdot \frac{e}{2}\cdot \frac{e}{1}\le  \left (\frac{e}{3}\right)^{n-2}\frac{e^2}{2}.$$